# Размеры потенциально DOM узла

Tags: jquery, dom, javascript

Есть ли способ узнать размеры потенциального DOM узла?

```
.square{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

var h = $('<div/>', {class: 'square'});
alert($(h).width()); // => 0
```

Comment: Можно. Но в потенциале таких объектов может быть очень много, так что хотелось бы послушать еще варианты.

Comment: оптимизируйте вставку, других способов нет, посмотрите мой пример, там  из % получаются пиксели, по другому это не посчитать. (вообще конечно не обязательно position: absolute, всё зависит от задачи)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вставьте его в dom с position absolute; и уберите сразу.

```
var h = $('<div/>', {class: 'square'});
h.appendTo('body');
h.css('position','absolute');
var w=h.width();
h.detach();
h.css('position','');
$('#out').text(w); //в пикселях
console.log(h)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/PSLbC/

если надо просто запись в css актуальную, то можно

```
var w=h.css(width); //вставлять в этом случае надо только если есть возможность наследования свойства css элементом
```